# Azure DevOps - Disable and Enable Repository

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure devOps. I disabled the repository but now want to enable it however the UI control is greyed out. I am guessing this is a permission issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is was a permissions issue, I removed myself from the project settings as an admin.